# Detect changes during bulk indexing

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using Elasticsearch v5.6.12 for our database. We update this frequently using the bulk REST api. Some of the time the individual requests won't change anything (i.e. the value of the document that Elasticsearch is already up to date). **How can I detect these instances?**

I saw this (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) but I'm not sure it's applicable in our situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`noop` detection](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_detecting_noop_updates) when checking the result of your bulk queries.

When the bulk query returns, you can iterate over each update result and check if the `result` field has a value of `noop` (vs `updated`)

```
# Say the document is indexed
PUT test/doc/1
{
  "test": "123"
}

# Now you want to bulk update it
POST test/doc/_bulk
{"update":{"_id": "1"}}
{"doc":{"test":"123"}}        <-- this will yield `result: noop`
{"update":{"_id": "1"}}
{"doc":{"test":"1234"}}       <-- this will yield `result: updated`
{"update":{"_id": "2"}}
{"doc":{"test":"3456"}, "doc_as_upsert": true}       <-- this will yield `result: created`
```

Result:

```
{
  "took" : 6,
  "errors" : false,
  "items" : [
    {
      "update" : {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_version" : 2,
        "result" : "noop",            <-- see "noop"
        "_shards" : {
          "total" : 2,
          "successful" : 1,
          "failed" : 0
        },
        "status" : 200
      }
    },
    {
      "update" : {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_version" : 3,
        "result" : "updated",            <-- see "updated"
        "_shards" : {
          "total" : 2,
          "successful" : 1,
          "failed" : 0
        },
        "_seq_no" : 2,
        "_primary_term" : 1,
        "status" : 200
      }
    },
    {
      "_index" : "test",
      "_type" : "doc",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_version" : 1,
      "result" : "created",            <-- see "created"
      "_shards" : {
        "total" : 2,
        "successful" : 1,
        "failed" : 0
      },
      "_seq_no" : 0,
      "_primary_term" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, when specifying `doc_as_upsert: true` for document with id 2, the document will be created and the `result` field value will be `created`

Comment: What will the result field be in the case that the document doesn't already exist?

Comment: It depends on what you're sending in your bulk query (index, update, etc). Feel free to show your bulk query

Comment: Also, is it able to give you the diff (what was there and what you have changed it to)?

Comment: So far we've been using index.

Comment: No ES will not give you the diff. See my updated answer to see if it fits your use case.

Comment: When using the "index" operation you cannot detect noops as the document will always be reindexed no matter whether there were changes or not.